# Mule Anypoint studio not working properly in ubuntu linux 16.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mule, mule-studio

I installed jdk 1.8 and set the **JAVA_HOME** variable in my **ubunut 16.04 LTS** machine.

After that I downloaded Anypoint studio and extracted the files in it. Then when I run the studio it is getting opened properly. But remaining controls seems not working properly.

For example, When I click on windows->preferences and searching for 'JRE', it is not searching at all. Did anyone has same/similar issues?

Comment: can u post the exception of what u r getting ?

Comment: got to windows-->preferences-->Java -->Installed JREs --> Edit You will be able to point it to the JDK you want from there.

Comment: I am not getting any exception. When I go to windows->preferences and in the filter I started typing jre it is showing up nothing. Even if I click on Installed JREs in that tree it is not displaying anything. Is this a issue with memory? Also when I go to New MuleProject, after few seconds it is showing a window to enter project details. But all the details are getting displayed only when I full screen (double click on top window bar) that window. Otherwise I could not see anything.

Comment: I installed Oracel jdk 8 in /usr/bin/java/jdk1.8.0_92 folder. Is that the cause of the issue? I don't have any clue, not exception nothing. But when I install STS, it is working perfectly.

Comment: And weird thing is Anypoint studio 5.3.x 2015 releases are working perfectly fine without any issue. Seems the current build (sudio 3.6.x) is not compatible with ubuntu 16.04 LTS or my machine is not compatible.

Comment: What version of Studio are you using? There's been some compatibility issues of the Eclipse plugin with GTK version 3 that have been fixed in Studio 6.0.2.

Comment: I am using studio 6.0.1 which is the latest one available for download right now. I am not using eclipse plugin. It's working perfectly fine in my Linux Mint Cinnamon 18 machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should check and see if Anypoint Studio supports Java 8 currently. I just switched to version 3.8 and my Studio seems to "want" Java 1.7. I have version 8 Java on my machine but I noticed that the latest version of Anypoint Studio (using 3.8 Mule EE) wants to use 1.7. I tried to select my 1.8 Java and it said that Anypoint Studio would still be using a compiler compliance level of 1.7.

Go read the documentation on the Mule site.

HTH